# Debug non verbose code in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I end up writing a lot of code like this:

```
String path = getAbsolutePath();
retriever.setDataSource(path);
```

instead of just

```
retriever.setDataSource(getAbsolutePath());
```

Simply because it's much easier to debug by putting a breakpoint on the second line in order to debug the output of the first.

Is there a good way to debug the output of the getAbsolutePath() without breaking the code up into multiple lines?

NOTE: getAbsolutePath() might not be a simple function. It might have multiple return statements or maybe not even include the source code. In other words - it might not be as simple as just going into getAbsolutePath() and putting a breakpoint at the last line with a return statment.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with explicitly setting values in your Java code.  It makes it easier to sprinkle System.out.println statements through your code.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a good way to debug the output of the getAbsolutePath() without breaking the code up into multiple lines?

You can set a breakpoint on the compound line, and then either:

- use Inspect to examine the return value of `getAbsolutePath()`
- add an Expression to look at the return value of `getAbsolutePath()`

Both of those alternatives will reevaluate the method though, so it's at least questionable whether that would be useful for anything stateful.

Next question is whether you want to.  If your concern is readability, I'd say that if you find yourself debugging such a compound statement that often, you *should* put it on a separate line because it's clearly important and complicated enough to deserve that bit of clarification.